# how to destroy the image button in android?

Tags: android, layout, timer, imageview, collision

i have a simple game ..theres a snow move down and a penguin in bottom layout ..we must protec the penguin from falling snow

And i want to ask you
how we can destroy the imageview (snow pictures) when we click it?
i set:

```
 lebah2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

but it just hidding ..because i create a timer to check the collision ..when the snow collision with penguin so the live is minus one ..if i put this code, the timer will always decrease live ..

```
for(int awal = 1 ; awal<=akhir; awal++)
                                    {
                                        ImageView lebah2 = (ImageView) findViewById(awal);
                                        int atas = lebah2.getTop();
                                        int left = lebah2.getLeft();
                                        if(atas >=180)
                                        {
                                            if(left >180 && left <240)
                                            {
                                                data.live--;
                                                 TextView nyawa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.live);
                                                 nyawa.setText(String.valueOf(data.live));
                                                 lebah2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            }
                                        }
```

what must i do?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the view like this:

```
((LinearLayout)lebah2.getParent()).removeView(lebah2);
```

you can also just skip the loop if the view is not visible:

```
if(iv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
   for(int awal = 1 ; awal<=akhir; awal++) {
      //Check if collision
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The view is not removed when you set the visibility as GONE. For exemple If you get all childs for a   parent the view will be counted.

Use This:

```
 ImageView lebah2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lebah2);

((RelativeLayout)lebah2.getParent()).removeView(lebah2);
```

Comment: View lebah2 = view.findViewById(R.id.lebah2);
((RelativeLayout)lebah2.getParent()).removeView(lebah2);

doesn't work for you?

Comment: methode findviewbyid is not applicable for view .. =(

Comment: when i click the imageview theres a classfile editor show in my eclipse